# Extracting value from table by name form panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get value from table by name. My table is

```
school = [['Jason',100],
            ['Alice',87.89],
            ['Mary',68]]

school = pd.DataFrame(school, columns=['Name','Grade'],dtype=float)
```

I want to return grade of `'Jason'`. I tried school['Jason'] to return 100 but it does not work.

How to return value by calling name from the table? Would be grateful for any kind of help and tips.

Comment: `school.loc[school.Name=='Jason','Grade']`

Comment: If you just want to look up, use a dictionary `school = dict([['Jason', 100], ['Alice', 87.89], ['Mary', 68]])`.  Otherwise, if you want a series use `school = pd.Series(dict([['Jason', 100], ['Alice', 87.89], ['Mary', 68]]))`

Comment: Thank you guys for prompt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
grades_of_jason = school[school['Name'] == Jason]['Grade'] # filter for rows with name = json, then get grade of those rows
```

```
print(list(grades_of_jason)[0]) # get first item of this series
100
```